# Media gallery images url instead of ID on WP API Response

Tags: images, gallery, wp-api

I'm getting this in my json response

```
"main_image": 
[
"11125,11122,11123,11127,11128"
],
```

Those are the ID's of my post, I need to get the URL of each ID in the 'thumbnail' size. I did't find any solution, just this code but It's more for Custom Meta of a plugin.

```
function xxx_past_poss_custom_metadata( $post_response, $post, $context ) {
    $meta = get_post_custom( $post['ID'] );
    $custom_fields = array();
    $xxx_image_gallery = array();

    foreach ( $meta['xxx_cmb_image_gallery'] as $key => $value ) {
        $value = wp_get_attachment_url($value);
        $xxx_image_gallery[ $key ] = $value;
    };

    foreach ( $meta as $key => $value ) {
        // Replace 'xxx_' with any custom metakey prefix (ie. '_' for private metadata's)
        if ( 'xxx_' !== substr( $key, 0, 1 ) ) {
            $custom_fields[ $key ] = $value;
        };
    }

    $post_response['xxx_image_gallery'] = $xxx_image_gallery;
    $post_response['custom_fields'] = $custom_fields;
    return $post_response;
}
add_filter( 'json_prepare_post', 'xxx_past_poss_custom_metadata', 10, 3 );
```

My meta it's called "media_gallery".

Any help will be very appreciated.

[UPDATE]

Seems like I wasn't even modifying my json response because of a plugin I had activated, turning it off made me declare my meta in my functions.php file and no I have this.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_fields', 1, 1);

function register_custom_fields(){

  register_rest_field(
    'job_listing',
    'thumbnail',
    array(
      'get_callback' => 'show_image'
    )
  );

}

function show_main_image($object, $field_name, $request){
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($object['id']);
  $main_image = $custom_fields['main_image'];

  return $main_image;
}
```

I can now modify the response but I still haven't been able to turn all this ID's: "11125,11122,11123,11127,11128" into URL sources.

My custom input saves the images id's like this: "11125,11122,11123,11127,11128", so was Pedro said is true it

> is an array with a single string inside

What I tried next was this:

```
function show_main_image($object, $field_name, $request){
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($object['id']);
  $main_image = $custom_fields['main_image'];

  foreach ( $main_image as $key => $value ) {
      $imagesID = explode(',',$value);
      foreach ($imagesID as $id => $value) {
        $result = wp_get_attachment_url($value);
        $custom_fields[ $id ] = $result;
      }
  };
  $image_urls = array();

  return $result;
}
```

But still no luck, now the "main_image" endpoint appears to be empty.

Comment: Are the IDs the images in the post? Have you looked at `wp_get_attachment_image_src`? It might be what you need: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

Comment: Yes, they're in the post, in a custom field named "main_image". The response shows the array value but I can't turn them into URL.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to achieve it is this:

```
function show_main_image($object, $field_name, $request){
    $custom_fields = get_post_custom($object['id']);
    $main_image = $custom_fields['main_image'];
    $arregloimg = explode(',',$main_image[0]);

    $image_urls = array();
    foreach ( $arregloimg as $key => $value ) {
        $image_urls[] = wp_get_attachment_url($value,'thumbnail');
    };

    return $image_urls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment I think what you need is `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

Wordpress saves attachments ( like images ) as a type of post. Might seem silly, but this means it saves all sorts of meta information about it, such as diferent sizes, captions etc. As a result, each image gets a post ID.

So assuming you have this array, which is parsed from your JSON:

```
$main_image = array( 11125, 11122, 11123, 11127, 11128 );
```

( Note that it seems your JSON is returning an array witha single string inside, instead of multiple integers )

You simply go through requesting the image URL at thumbnail size:

```
$image_urls = array();

foreach ( $main_image as $image_id ) {
    $image_urls[] = wp_get_attachent_image_src( $image_id, 'thumbnail' );
}
```

Now `$image_urls` is populated with ... image urls :)

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi Pedro, thanks for your help. I tried your code but didn't worked. I will elaborate my explanation a bit more. Seems like I wasn't even modifying my json response because of a plugin I had activated, turning it off made me declare my meta in my functions.php file and no I have this. (Code included in the Question update.